# LXDE Ubuntu - How do I run a command after computer resumes from sleep?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, lubuntu, lxde

I run

```
 xmodmap ~/.xmodmaprc
```

in order to swap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> keys. However, when I resume from sleep, this configuration gets reset. Where can I set it so it runs a script on resume so I don't have to go into the command line each time after I close the laptop lid?

Comment: Are you talking about the laptop's built-in keyboard or an external USB one?

Comment: built-in keboard

Comment: Could you include the (relevant) output from `xinput list` in your question and perhaps check if a keyboard appears in the output of `lsusb`? Also what Ubuntu version do you have?

Comment: Perhaps the answer(s) to [Ubuntu 12.10 xmodmap reset after usb plug/unplug](http://askubuntu.com/q/264232/74792) will help you.